# How can I make something like the Washington Post Social Reader?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-timeline

I make an app that automatically posts to my timeline using the following code:

```
  FB.api(
    '/me/linksku:read?article=<?php echo $permalink; ?>',
    'post',
    function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
      }
    }
```

However, this only works for me. It doesn't work for anyone else. How can I make something like the Washington Post Social Reader?

Comment: Give more info. Don't ask us to research what the Washington Post Social Reader does. You need to describe how you want this to work.

Comment: The Washington Post Social Reader uses Facebook's new Open Graph to automatically post the news articles that an user read to the user's timeline without the user having to do anything.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing will be visible to everyone on Facebook only after Facebook approves your actions after you submit them from your developer dashboard for approval.  Currently all approvals are pending until Facebook releases timeline to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement open graph on your website and set action types. Also open graph meta tags need to be implemented.

Look at this [link](http://dailygoodkarma.in/karmablog/) where open graph meta tags are implemented.